# Google App Engine Bitcoin Mining

Tags: google-app-engine, bitcoin

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2745.0

I saw this, and it's quite a dead thread.  I'm trying to implement this, but eclipse is having issues.

```
The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-endpoints.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory  lib /gaeminer-master/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem    
The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-jsr107cache-1.7.7.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory  lib /gaeminer-master/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem    
The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-api-labs.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory   lib /gaeminer-master/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem    
The App Engine SDK JAR appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.7.7.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory  lib /gaeminer-master/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem    
The App Engine SDK JAR datanucleus-appengine-1.0.10.final.jar is missing in the WEB-INF/lib directory   lib /gaeminer-master/war/WEB-INF    Unknown Google App Engine Problem
```

How do I fix this?

I've spent several hours pounding my head into a desk for this project. By the way, yes, I understand CPU mining doesn't make much money, I just wanted to see if this was possible.

Comment: Try asking the question on http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ there will be more interest over there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it pressing right button on the error (Markers Tab) -> Quick Fix -> Synchronize lib with JDK libraries. Try it and tell me if it helps you =)

Comment: Thank you! This helped me (didn't even know of the quick fix for those problems).